# What does this sentence mean ドリンコはママの味に?

Tags: words, sentence

It's a TV show episode title, so there isn't any context to be found, and I have a hard time figuring out what it means.

(ドリンコはママの味に)

Comment: You sure it's ドリンコはママの味**に** with nothing following it? or not just ドリンコはママの味 (with no に at the end) ?

Comment: the context is probably the contents of the episode. What happens in it? Is there a synopsys? Is ドリンコ a character's name?

Comment: This just sounds like a translation request to me.

Answer (score 1):

I googled the title. It wasドリンコはママの味
Fujiya (candy company)have a drink called drinkはママの味
It means it tastes like mommy made.
TV show made parody of Fujiya. ドリンコmeans someone's name or drink name maybe. But you need to watch the show.

Comment: The English term is "parody".

Comment: Thank you (^^)@lgor Skochinsky

Comment: You can edit your answer to improve it

Comment: Yes, I edited the comment.

Comment: ドリンコ is used probably as an alternative spelling for ドリンク (see [this](https://game8.co/games/Monster-Hunter-Rise/archives/325165) for example).